# SMTPAuthenticationError #503 Error: Already Authenticated

Tags: python, smtp

Hey everyone I am trying to make a Bitcoin price checker that will email me when the price falls below a certain amount. I am using smtplib, and when sending the email I am getting the below error. I have been trying to fix this for a while now so any and all help is appreciated. I'm really confused as to why this is happening since it says within the error message itself that authentication was successful.
Here is the code for sending the email:

def send_email():
    msg = MIMEMultipart()

```
password = your_password
msg['From'] = your_email
msg['To'] = send_email_to
msg['Subject'] = "Bitcome Price Dropping, Check now!"

message = "Dear " + your_name + "\nBitcoin prices are now " + str(bitcoin_rate) + ". Better buy quick. \nRegards, \n" + your_name

msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')

server.starttls()

server.login(msg['From'], password)

server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], message)

server.quit()

print("successfully sent mail to %s:" % (msg['To']))
print("Price of Bitcoin was at " + str(bitcoin_rate))
```

This is the error message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4wiW.png)

Comment: Luckily the error message tells you what to do! Alternatively you create an use an application password. And BTW: no spaces before the port.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it ending up being a problem with my gmail account. Despite me allowing access for less secure apps it was still blocking my script for sending emails. Clearing the captcha and running the code again ended up working. Thanks again.